# Attributed string click is not sensitive with UITextView

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsmutableattributedstring

Clickable text is not sensitive when touching, need stay finger for a while to trigger that event. Is there a method to resolve that?

Comment: This is the default behaviour of UILabel with a link or any actionable item.

Comment: You can try using this custom library or component. https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: Do you want a clickable UILabel or a part of string in UILabel that's clickable?

Comment: Instead of UILabel  you can use UIButton. Hopes it will helps you

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri part of string can be clickable.

Comment: If that's what you want, you can check my answer

Comment: @BollMose, you said `need stay finger for a while to trigger that event`. Does that mean you are looking for Long Press Recognizer on part of String on UITextView?

Comment: I need  a sensitive style as UIButton. @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri

Comment: Does that mean one click on string triggers a method? or do you need all UIControlEvents that are there for UIButton?

Answer (score 0):

From our discussion in comments, I believe that you asked for a way to make part of String clickable. For this you can use `NSAttributeString` along with `UITextView` to resolve your problem.

```
NSString *myString = @"Sample string - click";
NSMutableAttributedString *myAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myString];
[myAttributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSURL URLWithString:@"randomString"] range:[initString rangeOfString:@"click"]];

UITextView *myNonEditableTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 200, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 120, 100)];
myNonEditableTextView.delegate = self;
myNonEditableTextView.attributedText = myAttributedString;
myNonEditableTextView.editable = NO;
[self.view addSubview: myNonEditableTextView];

// delegate functions for UITextView

// - For versions >= iOS 10, this delegate function should be used 
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange interaction:(UITextItemInteraction)interaction {
    [self performAction];
    return NO;
}

// - For versions < iOS 10, this delegate function should be used
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange {
    [self performAction];
    return NO;
}
```

Hope this helps :) and let me know if you need a swift version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am sorry I change the title because I use UITextView not UILabel(UILabel cannot clickable automatically).

Comment: That's great. My answer is for UITextView. Do you want a swift version for this?